# Why is Jquery adding inline styles to my html?

Tags: jquery, css, styles, inline

I am using CSS to restyle a radio group like this:

[image: Restyles radio group]

It's being done by hiding nesting the actual input (the button) inside the label tag, and then setting the input itself to `display:none` in the CSS, and styling the label itself to become to button, as such:

```
<label for="likert1" class="likert">
   <input type="radio" id="likert1" name="patientViewGroup" value="1">
   1
</label>
```

It can be done all with CSS... but because SOME browsers (I'm lookin' at you, IE8 and below) don't recognize the `:checked` pseudoclass, doing it that way men that your actual input - which is what will pass the value out of the form - doesn't always register that it is checked, so JQuery to the rescue.

I'm now using JQuery to set addClass ".amClicked" when one of the labels is clicked, at which time it also toggles the radio's "checked" attribute to "true," and removes the "amChecked" class from the siblings. Easy, right? Here's that JQuery code:

```
$('.likert').on("click",function() {
    console.log("clikcy!");
    if(!$(this).hasClass('amChecked')) { 
        $(this).addClass("amChecked");
        $(this).children(":radio").attr("checked",true).css("display","none");
    }
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("amChecked")
                       .children(":radio").css("display","none");
});
```

Well, it WOULD be, except that JQuery, for some reason, seems hell-bent on adding in-line "style" tag to my `<input>` that is overriding my `display: none;` and un-hiding the radio button itself, like #3 below:

[image: After a click - the button appears!]

And here's what that input code looks like after a click:

```
<input type="radio" id="likert3" name="patientViewGroup" value="3" 
       checked="checked" style="display: inline-block; " class="amChecked">
```

Even worse, adding `.css("display","none")` to my click code (as you can see above) doesn't override it - the button still shows up. If I don't add it to the removeClass line, that button just stays there, unchecked, as so:

[image]

SO - can anyone tell me WHY Jquery is adding this, unbidden, to my code, and is there anything I can do to stop or override it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle example?

Comment: You're adding `.amChecked` not `.amClicked`

Comment: You should not use `display: none` for the hidden radio buttons. Use `position: absolute; left: -10000px;` instead.  IE will not honor "click" events on radio buttons or checkboxes that are explicitly hidden with `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: But even then,  if the hidden radio element is nested within the element that you're clicking to select that radio element...what does it matter?

Comment: Thanks, Pointy, that's VERY good advice, and seems to have put me on the proper track to a solution.

Comment: Did you get an acceptable answer to this? Kinda left us hanging!

Comment: I DID get my scale working, but I did NOT get a satisfactory answer as to why jQuery was adding that inline style code... particularly the pesky disply: none. Implementing Pointy's suggestion obviated the need for it, though; it was an unexplained artifact, not the root of my problem. tPlummer's suggestion below was a good one as well. If you are interested, I can perhaps create a fiddle with my final code and a description, though not until next week.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, jQuery is always going to push styles inline.  It effects elements, not the page or stylesheet defined styles.  It only knows the element exists because you pointed it to that element.

Also, I wouldn't put the radio inside the label.  That might be what's causing the problem.

In your stylesheet or where ever your styles are defined:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Why not use a class with `display:none;` instead of a `.css()`? `.addClass('hidden')`., `.removeClass('hidden')` should work.

Then you can use that where ever.

Going to build a fiddle in the mean time to test.

**EDIT** Here's a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KLfjW/2/)
Actually, just started looking at your jQuery.  I'm not sure I see what the intended result is?  You just want to click an element and it changes the radio, right?

With radio buttons, you don't have to set something to make them unselected, they will unselect on their own.

If you set up a hidden value instead of `display: none;` radio values, you're not going to run into issues mentioned in the question's comments.  Then you just set a function to change the value of the hidden value based on some attribute of the element you clicked.

Comment: Good point... didn't give me my complete answer, but a good call!

Comment: See my fiddle update.  Also, complete answer is jQuery always pushes `.css()` inline.

Comment: Clicking directly on a radio button (or its parent label) clears the checked state of other radio elements in the group. However, programmatically setting a radio's `checked` state does NOT affect others in the group. As far as we know from the OP's code, the click event **will** propagate from the label to its child input. In other cases, bubbling might be stopped, or the click target might not contain the radio being affected. [Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVHwG/2/) which omits the `.removeAttr('checked')` on the other radio options.

Comment: As far as I know, any "checked" radio buttons with the same name only allow for one "checked" instance at a time, as far as standard HTML forms are concerned.  Whether that changes when manipulating the form elements in jQuery is beyond me.  I wouldn't recommend this practice so I can't really speak on the matter. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to set the radio inputs' `display`, and do not alter it with jQuery.

```
label.likert > input {
    display: none;
}
```

Also, to toggle the "checked" attribute, you assign it a value of "checked". To "uncheck", you remove the attribute.

```
$('label.likert').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('amChecked')) {
        $(this).addClass('amChecked').children(':radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }

    $(this).siblings('.amChecked').removeClass('amChecked').children(':radio').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

I threw it together in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVHwG/1/).

Comment: Thanks, Rodney, but even in the JSFiddle, it doesn't hide the actual radio buttons when they are checked - I'm trying to keep them hidden at all times, showing only the styled labels. Thanks for pointing out my unchained JQuery statements, though - I forgot to tighten that up.

Comment: If you want them hidden at all times, don't nest them in the label.  `<label>` is a special tag.

Comment: My answer and fiddle now keep them hidden.